# Classic ASP: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: sql-server-2012, asp-classic, iis-7

I am using Classic ASP with a connection string of:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

IIS is using windows authentication and anonymous is disabled.

When I view my website, I get:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e4d' 

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. 

/inc/db.asp, line 8
```

I've tried reading other questions/answers but can't see the wood through the trees. Any advice?

I want the user that has logged in with their NT credentials to connect to the DB.

Thanks

Comment: With Classic ASP the user connecting to the database is the website's IUSR account.  You may find it easier to create an SQL Server login for your website and use a connection string like `Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=yourServer;Initial Catalog=yourDataBase;
User Id=yourUsername;Password=yourPassword;`

Comment: That won't work as I need the user logging in to be the one accessing their data

Comment: You're missing the point.  It isn't the user who is logging in to the database, it's a special account on your server.  If you want users to access their own data you need to do it at a later stage with an SQL query, after the connection to the database has been made.

Comment: Oh right - so there's no way for the user who's authenticated to the site to 'connect' to the database, instead they have to do it at a later stage as you suggest?